# Access close Recordset in error handling

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba

I was wondering about error handling. If an error occurs during code execution, and I have a recordset open, should I close it? Attempting a recordset.close operation can raise an error, and since I'm inside an error handling code part, it will be an unhandled error.

If I send the code back to continue at another label, then it can become infinite loop. Now adding one boolean to check if this is the first time the error appeared would work, but do I really need all this fuss? **Will the connection stay open if the code terminates and I don't close it? Will it cause trouble later?**

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblSetting")
On Error GoTo handler

    'do things

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

Exit Sub

handler:
 rs.Close
 'Set rs = Nothing '-this one is not necessary, as terminating the sub should clear up all references to it, hence Garbage Collector can pick it up
End Sub
```

This would work, but... really?

```
...
Termination:
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
Exit Sub

handler:
 if ErrorHappened=True then
  msgbox "fatal error"
  exit sub
 else
  ErrorHappened=True
  resume termination
 End If
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's good practice to close currently opened recordsets and connections. There's tons of reasons, see: [Pooling in the Microsoft Data Access Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810829.aspx). This article is pretty old, but the main thing is kept...

I'd improve your code this way:

```
Exit_Subroutine:
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore errors to be able to execute each line
    If Not rst is Nothing Then rst.Close: Set rst = Nothing
    'do the same for the connection object!
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error" & Err.Number
    Resume Exit_Subroutine
```

You have to be sure that `rst` object is not nothing before you attampt to close it.

Comment: Well, the hard way it is, then... Thanks!

Comment: I still wouldn't put it directly into the error hander though... Or nothing else can cause an error when closing a recordset besides not being set?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, i've been bit busy. I added extra lines to code and improved error handler. This is the quite often piece of code i'm using - for general purposes. Of course, you can change it to catch and deal with specific error number.

Answer (score 1):

VBA has automatic garbage collection. Unless something goes wrong inside the VBA compiler, all objects are released when they go out of scope. In your example:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

'do things
Exit Sub

'do things
End Sub
```

... rs is released at the End Sub, and is automatically closed. (FWIW, you can see this by examining the compiled code).

Classic ASP did not have scope like this, and objects never went out of scope and recordsets were never automatically released. For this reason, ALL Microsoft VBA EXAMPLES SHOW EXPLICIT CLOSE AND RELEASE. It has to be done that way for ASP Classic.

There are two other reasons for doing explicit close and release:

1) C /C++ programmers don't have automatic memory management. They were filled with horror and disgust at the idea of leaving objects open. This is a coding style.

2) Some people claim that in some unidentified error condition, somehow local objects with no remaining references aren't automatically closed correctly. I've never seen that. I've never seen that documented. I've never read of an actual specific example. But hey, some people make that claim: perhaps it's true.